# WebSocket connection to 'wss://emqx.domain.com:8084/mqtt' failed

Tags: websocket, mqtt, mqtt.js, emqx

why websocket client is not able to connect to my emqx server? I am using the aws ec2 instance. in which I run two containers caddy and emqx. I have used Caddy as a reverse proxy to forward all the requests to emqx. I am able to open the emqx dashboard on emqx.domain.com. but when I go to the Diagnose section and try to connect to websocket client, it shows a pop-up "" when I click on the connect button. when I inspect the page and open a console it's showing "WebSocket connection to 'wss://emqx.domain.com:8084/mqtt' failed".

I have mapped my server IP to the domain name emqx.domain.co

**When I disable the caddy proxy**

```
when I open port 18083 on the ec2 security group
78.34.23.434 - opens emqx dashboard

When I open port 18083,8083 
78.34.23.434 - opens emqx dashboard and websocket client connected using websocket protocol

When I open ports 18083,8083,8084
78.34.23.434 - opens emqx dashboard and websocket client connected using websocket protocol, but not connected using websocket-secure protocol.
```

**when i enable the caddy proxy**

```
When I open ports 18083,8083,8084
78.34.23.434 - opens emqx dashboard but not connected using websocket-secure and websocket protocol.
```

Caddyfile:

```
emqx.domain.com {
  reverse_proxy emqx:18083
}
was://emqx.domain.com:8084/mqtt {
  reverse_proxy emqx:8084
}
```

docker-compose-caddy.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  caddy:
    image: caddy:2.2.1-alpine
    container_name: caddy
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - ./site:/srv
      - ./caddy_config:/config
      - ./caddy_data:/data
      - ./Caddyfile:/etc/caddy/Caddyfile
```

docker-compose-emqx.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  emqx:
    image: emqx/emqx
    container_name: emqx
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./data:/opt/emqx/data
      - ./log:/opt/emqx/log
    environment:
      - EMQX_NAME=emqx
      - EMQX_LISTENER__TCP__EXTERNAL=1883
      - EMQX_LOADED_PLUGINS="emqx_management,emqx_dashboard,emqx_bridge_mqtt,emqx_sn"
      - EMQX_LISTENER__TCP__EXTERNAL=8883 # Add another listener for SSL/TLS
      - EMQX_LISTENER__WEBSOCKET__EXTERNAL=8083 # Add a WebSocket listener
      - EMQX_LISTENER__WEBSOCKET_SECURE__EXTERNAL=8084
    ports:
      - 1883:1883       #TCP
      - 8083:8083       #WEBSOCKET
      - 8084:8084       #WEBSOCKET_SECURE
      - 8883:8883       #SSL/TSL
      - 18083:18083     #DASHBOARD
```

I want to connect my websocket client to my emqx server. please help me solve this error. Are there any free open-source alternatives for emqx??

Comment: "why websocket client is not able to connect to my emqx server?" you are attempting to connect to port 8084 but the included Caddyfile contains no instructions to listen on that port. Please state what you are expecting caddy to do (e.g. do you want the dashboard and websocket server presented on a single external port, will caddy handle TLS and communicate with EMQX via http?).

Comment: I updated the caddy file to forward the request to port 8084. still, it's not working.

Comment: Is `was:` a typo (assume you mean `wss:` but as `https` is the default this should not be needed)? If you are going to do that you probably want the destination to be port `8083` (allow caddy to handle the TLS and communicate via HTTP with EMQX - alternatively [see this](https://caddyserver.com/docs/quick-starts/reverse-proxy#https-from-proxy-to-backend)). Again you need to tell us exactly what you are trying to accomplish re TLS termination.

Comment: Hello, I want to establish a connection to MQTT over WebSocket, now I am using nginx instead of caddy as a reverse proxy. I tried using emqx's latest version and nginx as a reverse proxy and access dashboard on my custom domain emqx.test.co, But when trying to connect to the websocket client from the emqx dashboard I get a connection failure, Can you please help here?

Comment: "Can you please help here?" - we cannot help without full details (see previous comments).

Comment: @Brits I updated the question and added the nginx.conf file. please check and let me know why its getting this errors

Comment: I'm confused; the error is about connecting to port `8083`/`8084` but your nginx config only covers ports `80` and `443` (it appears that you are not accessing the site via nginx?). There are too many variables here. Jumping from caddy (a perfectly workable proxy) to nginx has just confused things further (please pick a proxy and then respond to any comments; i.e. you have still not responded to my comment re `was:`).